# Calculating congruence module

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm about to do an exam which includes congruence. I can calculate them but it takes me forever (so I'll lose time for other questions).

For instance, $358^{251}$ (mod 1457).
\begin{align*}
358^{251} \equiv (358^3)^{83}\times358^2\equiv325^{83}\times 1405\equiv (325^4)^{20}\times 325^3 \times 1405\\
\equiv(1149)^{20}\times 1448\equiv 159^{10}\times 1448 \equiv497^2\times 1448 \equiv 301 \text{ (mod 1457)}.
\end{align*}
The above took me around 15 minutes to calculate (I can only use the standard casio fx-83GT, or similar). Is this a matter of doing more exercises and becoming faster, or am I missing a trick somewhere?

Many thanks!

Comment: Iterated squaring is, at least, systematic and may involve fewer operations.

Comment: Or, in this particular case, note that $1457=31\times 47$ so it is *much* easier to just work with the two prime factors.

Comment: @lulu can you please explain what you mean??

Comment: With which hint?

Comment: @lulu the prime factors please, I can get them using my calculator. Thanks!

Comment: Well, $358\equiv 27\pmod {31}$ and $251\equiv 11\pmod {30}$ so $358^{251}\equiv 27^{11}\pmod {31}$.  Easy.  $47$ is no harder.  Then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to get the solution mod $31\times 47$.

Comment: @lulu thanks! I didn't think of that

Comment: Sorry, I should have written $358\equiv 17\pmod {31}$.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to notice that $(358)^2 \equiv 1405 \equiv (-52) \pmod{1457}.$  Also, $251$ is very close to $256 = 2^8$.  So I would have considered $(-52)$ as $k_1$, where $k_{n+1} = (k_n)^2 ~:~ n \in \{1,2,\cdots, 7\}.$  This would have given you $(358)^{(256)} \pmod{1457}.$  After reading the other comments, it is *unclear* to me that (with a calculator) this approach is inferior to factoring $(1457)$.

Comment: Refining the previous comment, if you wish to avoid being concerned about $(358)^{(-1)} \pmod{1457}$, you can simply express $(251)$ in binary code as $2^{128} + 2^{64} + \cdots.$  Then, the constants of $k_1, \cdots, k_8$ from my last comment come **individually** into play.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

I would use first the *Chinese remainder theorem*: as $1457=31×47$,
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/1457\mathbf Z&\simeq \mathbf Z/31\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/47\mathbf Z \\
x\bmod1457&\mapsto(x\bmod31, x\bmod 47),
\end{align}
so that you'll have to compute, according to Euler's theorem,
$$358^{251}\bmod 31=7^{251}=7^{251\bmod{30}}=7^{11}\bmod 31,$$
and similarly modulo 47.

These powers are calculated efficiently with the *fast exponentiation algorithm*. Once you have them, use the inverse isomorphism deduced from a Bézout's relation $\;31u+47v=1$:
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/31\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/47\mathbf Z &\simeq \mathbf Z/1457\mathbf Z \\
(\alpha\bmod31, \beta\bmod 47)&\mapsto 31u\beta+47v\alpha\bmod 1457.
\end{align}